# Property of the inner product of Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H_1\subset H_2\subset H_3$ be three continuosly embedded and dense complex Hilbert spaces, where $H_3$ is the dual space of $H_1$ and $A:H_1\longrightarrow H_2$ and $B:H_1\longrightarrow H_3$ be two operators. Let $u\in H_1$ and $v\in K\subset H_1$ and consider the scalar product
$$ (Au, v) = (Bu, v).$$

On my notes there is something not clear for me, i.e. the following sentence. "If we suppose $K$ be dense in $H_1$, then we have $Au = Bu$."

I don't understand why it is true. Could anyone please help?

I am sorry if the question is trivial.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are these real or complex Hilbert spaces? And I assume that you mean $H_3$ is equipped with an inner-product $(\cdot,\cdot)$, which $H_1$ and $H_2$ inherit, and this inner product satisfies $(Au,v)=(Bu,v)$ for all $u\in H_1$ and $v\in K$?

Comment: I'm a little unclear on the quantifiers here. I'm guessing $u$ and $K \subseteq H_1$ are fixed, and, $\forall v \in K, (Au, v) = (Bu, v)$?

Comment: Yes @K.Power, as you said. And they  are complex Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @user79 You are more likely to get a good answer on this site if you include those details, so that there is no ambiguity, and also include your thoughts on the matter.

Comment: I might be missing something, but isn't it simply that you have two vectors $x,y \in H_3$  such that $(x,v) = (y,v)$ for every $v \in K$ where $K\subset H_3$ is dense and so $x=y$?